# How to jump to the first line of the C/C++ function using vim?

Tags: vim, vi

Is there a set of commands to jump between various elements of the C/C++ source code in `vim`? I know `ctags` but that offers limited functionality.

For example, is it possible to jump to the first line of the C/C++ function and come back from any line within the function.

I find myself keep scrolling up to find which function I am in while reviewing the code or searching a text/pattern in the source code.

Answer (score 3):

In languages where code is structured as methods in classes, [`[m`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#[m) jumps to the start of the method. That's good in a C++ class, but in a C or C++ toplevel function it'll bring you to the start of the second-outermost block. Another [`[{`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#[%7B) will bring you to the outermost brace.

In languages with C-like syntax, in files formatted with `{` on its own line at the start of a function, [`[[`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#[[) jumps to the previous brace in column 1.

Press [Ctrl-O](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#CTRL-O) to jump back.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of `[{`  but it only takes you to previous unmatched brace - not the outermost. `[[` could be a solution for those have `{` in the first column but   not all code follows that convention so unfortunately that does not work too.

Answer (score 1):

<s>As far as I know that is not possible with a simple vim command.</s>

From the vim manual (:help section):

> The "]" and "[" commands stop at the '{' or '}' in the first column.  This is
>   useful to find the start or end of a function in a C program.
>
> (...)
>
> If your '{' or '}' are not in the first column, and you would like to use " [["
>   and "]]" anyway, try these mappings:
>
> `:map [[ ?{<CR>w99[{
>   :map ][ /}<CR>b99]}
>   :map ]] j0[[%/{<CR>
>   :map [] k$][%?}<CR>`

---

If you need it for code orientation consider using folds. For example with `set foldmethod=syntax` press `zC` while in a function to close it and see the function name, `zO` to reverse it and jump back to the line you were on.

Another possibility for orientation is to use a plugin such as [tagbar](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/tagbar) that among others highlights the current function.